# Why does pthread_join assign joined thread's return value via a pointer but not via a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c

Why does `pthread_join` assign joined thread's return value to given variable when given a pointer to the variable, but not when given a pointer to a pointer to the variable which is how the `pthread_join`'s signature instructs?

For example, I'd expect the following program to print:

```
Status of pthread_create: 0
Hello from child thread!
Status of pthread_join: 0, return value of the joined thread: 42
```

but instead it prints:

```
Status of pthread_create: 0
Hello from child thread!
Status of pthread_join: 0, return value of the joined thread: 0
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int hello_world(void* arg) {
    printf(arg);
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    char* foo = "Hello from child thread!\n";
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int status_created = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, (void*)&hello_world, foo);
    printf("Status of pthread_create: %d\n", status_created);
    int status_child;
    int* status_child_ptr = &status_child;
    int status_joined = pthread_join(thread_id, (void**)&status_child_ptr);
    printf(
        "Status of pthread_join: %d, return value of the joined thread: %d\n",
        status_joined, status_child
    );
    return 0;
}
```

The program does print what I expect if I remove the `&` from `(void**)&status_child_ptr`, i.e. if I give a pointer instead of a pointer to a pointer as an argument. Why is that? Is `status_child` actually a pointer already?

Comment: That's not a valid worker routine. It must return a `void*`. Your program suffers from undefined behaviour. /// `&status_child_ptr` is not compatible with `void**`. This is also undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's rather pointless to ask why the program doesn't do what you want when you don't use the proper types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hello_world` function doesn't fit the signature of a function that can be passed to `pthread_create`.  Such a function is required to return a value of type `void *`.  Your code contains [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because this function is being called through an incompatible function pointer type.

You'll need to change the function to return a `void *`.  It is safe to convert an integer to a pointer and back, so you'll need to cast the return value to type `void *`, then in the `main` function you'll need to cast the returned `void *` value back to type `int`.

```
void *hello_world(void* arg) {
    printf(arg);
    return (void *)42;
}

int main()
{
    char* foo = "Hello from child thread!\n";
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int status_created=pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, (void*)&hello_world, foo);
    printf("Status of pthread_create: %d\n", status_created);
    void* status_child_ptr;
    int status_joined = pthread_join(thread_id, &status_child_ptr);
    int status_child = (int)status_child_ptr;
    printf(
        "Status of pthread_join: %d, return value of the joined thread: %d\n",
        status_joined, status_child
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize function signature mismatch would incur undefined behavior, so I was completely lost.